# Shiny Custom Input Binding for LimitSlider

Tags: input, slider, shiny, jquery-ui-slider

I'm trying to write a custom input widget for Shiny (following this: http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/building-inputs.html), wrapping the jQuery UI Limitslider (http://vanderlee.github.io/limitslider/) -- basically, I want a slider with 3 nodes to paramaterize a triangle distribution.  I'm struggling to get Shiny to "see" the change events.

Here's my **app.R** script:

```
library(shiny)

limitSlider <- function(id, label, a, b, c, min = a, max = b) {
   div(class = 'form-group shiny-input-container',
       tags$label(label),
         div(class = "ui-limitslider", 
             id = id,
             `data-a` = a,
             `data-b` = b,
             `data-c` = c,
             `data-min` = min,
             `data-max` = max)
   )
}

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(

  tags$head(
    tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", type = "text/css",
              href = "jquery-ui.css")
  ),

  tags$head(
    tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", type = "text/css",
              href = "limitslider.css")
  ),

  tags$head(
    tags$script(src = "jquery-ui.js")
  ),

  tags$head(
    tags$script(src = "limitslider.js")
  ),

  tags$head(
    tags$script(src = "limitslidershiny.js")
  ),

  tags$head(
    tags$script(src = "limitsliderinputbinding.js")
  ),

  titlePanel("Test Limit Slider"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      limitSlider("test1", "Test 1:", a = 25, b = 110, c = 80,
                   min = 0, max = 200),
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tableOutput("values")
    )
  )
))


server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  sliderValues <- reactive({

    data.frame(
      Name  = c("test1"),
      Value = c(as.character(c(paste(input$test1, collapse = ' '))))
    )

  })

  output$values <- renderTable({
    sliderValues()
  })

})

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

As you can see I load a sequence of CSS and JS files at the top to make the thing work -- they live in a "www" directory.  Here's my **limitslidershiny.js** file -- and I don't think the problem is here:

```
$(function() {

  $('.ui-limitslider').each(function(){

    // a,b,c correspond to the rtriangle function signature
    var a = $(this).data('a');
    var c = $(this).data('c');
    var b = $(this).data('b');

    // the rest of these correspond to the limitslider API
    var min = $(this).data('min');
    var max = $(this).data('max');

    $(this).limitslider({
      values: [a, c, b],
      gap: 0,
      label: true,
      min: min,
      max: max
    });
  });
});
```

Here's my **limitsliderinputbinding.js** script:

```
var limitSliderInputBinding = new Shiny.InputBinding();

$.extend(limitSliderInputBinding, {

  find: function(scope) {
    return $(scope).find(".ui-limitslider");
  },

  getValue: function(el) {
    return $(el).limitslider("values");  
  },

  setValue: function(el, values) {
    $(el).limitslider("values", values);
  },

  subscribe: function(el, callback) {
    $(el).on("slidechange.limitSliderInputBinding", function(e) {
      callback();
    });
  },

  unsubscribe: function(el) {
    $(el).off(".limitSliderInputBinding");
  }

});

Shiny.inputBindings.register(limitSliderInputBinding);
```

I think, but am not sure, that the issue lies somewhere in the **subscribe** property.

I'm using jQuery UI v1.11.4.  If anyone has any tips or suggestions or things to try, I'd welcome the help!

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, some colleagues helped me figure this out.  It turns out that limitslider, built on jQuery-UI, doesn't come with a "change" function initialized.  So, these fixes work:

```
$(this).limitslider({
   values: [a, c, b],
   gap: 0,
   label: true,
   min: min,
   max: max,
   change: function(event, ui){}
})
```

I made that modification to my **limitslidershiny.js** file.

It also turns out that the event type that gets thrown is called "limitsliderchange" (you can see that by doing console.log(event)).

So, based on that, I made these changes to the limitsliderinputbinding.js file:

```
subscribe: function(el, callback) {
  $(el).on("limitsliderchange.limitSliderInputBinding", function(e) {
    callback();
  });
}
```

...and similarly to unsubscribe.